# Bluetooth earpiece pairs, connects, but plays no sound.

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, headset

My earpiece worked fine until BOOM, it didn't. (Suspicion: I had recently run "Driver Booster 2", but I seem to recall the earpiece working after that - at least for awhile...Correlation, Causation)? 
I've uninstalled and reinstalled the software for the adapter, updated drivers (through Device Manager), Paired and Removed ad nauseum. Restarted, and repeated all of the above too many times.
The short version is that my earpiece: pairs; connects; shows up as a working device (no yellow yield signs with exclamation points); has all services working properly (BT AV, BT Hands-free, BT Headset and BT Remote Control); it is selected as my default device in "Sound" (with a very positive-looking green check mark); displays a pulsing (visual) meter signal (both in "Sound" and "Volume Mixer"...but I can't HEAR anything. (And yes, the earpiece is powered on and volume on high).

I CAN hear the Windows start-up sounds if I have my earpiece on at start-up (so the connection is being made), but once everything is "on" (Outlook by default, plus whatever else is in the background), I can't coax anything out of it.

Plantronics Voyager Pro+
IOGear Bluetooth 2.1 USB Adapter
HP Z420 Tower with Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
NVIDEA HD Audio and Realtek HD Audio  ??